# How to assign different classes via ngClass to facilitate an animation on a value change vs that value already being true on load?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, animation

I am not sure how to word this question, please edit it as necessary for clarity.

I'm trying to provide an animation if the value of an object changes, this was easy to do with `ngClass`. I assign a class to the element based on a value on the object. However, if the value that determines the class is already true upon load, the animation still plays. How can I get around this? I can't rely on user input to trigger the change either, as there are asynchronous application events that may change the object value as well.

<strike>Example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s6cdgyLb/</strike> AngularJS doesn't want to play with JSFiddle...
Example Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/LPJXRq1SWQWrqGaow5tR?p=preview

I am trying to achieve this kind of flow:

> `Page Load --> Question Answered --> color green`
>
> `User Answers Question --> Animate --> color green`

I'm getting this flow:

> `Page Load --> Question Answered --> Animate  --> color green`
>
> `User Answers Question --> Animate --> color green`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp2', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.list = [
        {
           value: "Some stuff",
           answered: true
        },
        {
           value: "More Stuff",
           answered: false        
        }
    ];
}]);

myApp.directive('questionCheckbox', function(){
    function link(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('click', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                question.answered = element.checked;
            })
        });
    };
    return {
        link: link
    }
});
```

```css
        @keyframes answered {
            0% {background-color: inherit;}
            70% {background-color: hsla(125, 100%, 34%, 0.65);}
            100% {background-color: hsla(125, 100%, 34%, 0.2);}
        }        
        
        .answered {
            animation: answered 2s;
            animation-fill-mode:forwards;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="myController">
      <div ng-repeat="question in list">
        <div ng-class="{answered: question.answered}">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="question.answered">
          <span>{{question.value}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you want to accomplish this without javascript, you might try having two separate classes, one for onload elements you don't want the animation applied to, and one for elements you want the animation applied to.

Comment: @BlackyWolf I updated my question. Realized it was more specific to how I was doing this in angular, and the problem is how would I apply the classes with angular for the animation.

Comment: I'll keep working on it, but for now if you need a "quick fix" I suggest going with Aarons two property idea.

Comment: @BlackyWolf No need for a quick fix, I'm working on a project so something solid is best. Don't put too much work into something for just my sake though :o

Answer (score 0):

You can create the behavior using CSS transitions instead. This works because angular renders the template initially with the "answered" class in place, so it never triggers the transition.

```
.answered {
  background: hsla(125, 100%, 34%, 0.2);
  transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, I'm updating my JSFiddle so it more accurately describes the specific problem. I realized shortly after posting that this was more specific to my AngularJS way of doing it than CSS/JS in general.

Comment: That's the only change you need to make, simply use transition instead of animation.

Comment: If you'd prefer to resolve this strictly by some means of ng-class, I believe you'll need to store 2 properties per question... "just-answered" and "previously-answered" and animate appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the below may be useful. Note, that the animation does get cut off if another checkbox is clicked before it finishes. I forked my changes from your plunkr if you want to see them under version.

So here is the code I used. Inside the controller underneath `$scope.list` I put (the below code) to control the `.plain` and `.animated` classes:

```
$scope.setIndex = function (index, answered) {
    if (answered) {
        $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
    }
};
```

I used three different classes to control the look:

```
.answered {
    background-color: hsla(125, 100%, 34%, 0.2);
}

.animated {
    animation: answered 2s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

.plain {
    background: none;
}
```

And finally, the HTML I added was (this) to control the `.animated` and `.plain` classes:

```
<div ng-class="{answered: question.answered, animated: $index === selectedIndex, plain: !question.answered}">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="question.answered"
           ng-click="setIndex($index, question.answered)">
    <span>{{question.value}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, very nice. However, the biggest problem that I'm trying to tackle is the animation triggering if the value was changed without user interaction. I can't rely on user input for the animation. I'll dig into this a bit further and see if I can do this, thank you for your reply.